# How does this 2d noise generation function work? Does it have a name?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, noise, noise-generator

I came across this 2D noise function in the [Book of Shaders](https://thebookofshaders.com/11/)

```
float noise(vec2 st) {
  vec2 integerPart = floor(st);
  vec2 fractionalPart = fract(st);

  float s00 = random(integerPart);
  float s01 = random(integerPart + vec2(0.0, 1.0));
  float s10 = random(integerPart + vec2(1.0, 0.0));
  float s11 = random(integerPart + vec2(1.0, 1.0));

  float dx1 = s10 - s00;
  float dx2 = s11 - s01;
  float dy1 = s01 - s00;
  float dy2 = s11 - s10;

  float alpha = smoothstep(0.0, 1.0, fractionalPart.x);
  float beta = smoothstep(0.0, 1.0, fractionalPart.y);

  return s00 + alpha * dx1 + (1 - alpha) * beta * dy1 + alpha * beta * dy2; 
}
```

It is clear what this function does: it generates four random numbers at the vertices of a square, then interpolates them. What I am finding difficult is understanding why the interpolation (the `s00 + alpha * dx1 + (1 - alpha) * beta * dy1 + alpha * beta * dy2` expression) works. How is it interpolating the four values when it does not seem to be symmetric in the x and y values?

Comment: It's difficult to say for sure without knowing what random(vec2) and smoothstep() do. Neither is obvious.

Comment: random() will create a seeded random vector. Smoothstep is likely a sigmoid transform of the interval 0-1. The code then does bilinear interpolation of the four values.

Comment: The answer is it is symmetrical if you expand it out. replace dx1, dy1, dy2 with the S expressions. (It's not actually 2D linear interpolation, but called bilinear).

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean Yes. It's bilinear interpolation. (For the OP, a bilinear interpolation of a 4 points in 3d provides the surface you'd get with a soap film stretched across a hoop of straight lines joining the points.)  But `random` is producing a `float`, not a vector. The listing is in the linked document. It takes the sine of a dot product with a magic constant vector and then  extracts the fractional part, which is pretty bizarre.

Comment: You found the algorithm in the "Book of Shaders" which explains that this is called value noise, and has quite a lot of text about how it works. What specific problems did you have understanding what was written there?

Comment: @Gene it's not bizarre. The idea is to pick a random value at each integer grid point (x, y), and to interpolate between them to produce a 2d random noise texture that is somewhat smooth while still being random. Perlin noise is the (Oscar-winning) prime example of this, which fixes some problems in the simpler idea listed here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise . Perlin noise and variants are used extensively in computer graphics.

Comment: @PaulHankin Thanks. I expected something called `random` to be generating a uniform random variable, as that name conventionally implies 99.9% of the time. Didn't recognize the function as a Perlin noise generator.

Answer (score 0):

If you expand the last line, it's:

```
return s00 * (1-alpha) * (1-beta) +
       s10 * alpha * (1-beta) +
       s01 * (1-alpha) * beta +
       s11 * alpha * beta;
```

Which is symmetric in x and y.  If you add up the weights:

```
alpha * beta + (1-alpha) * beta  + alpha * (1-beta) + (1-alpha) * (1-beta)
= (alpha + 1-alpha) * beta + (alpha + 1-alpha) * (1-beta)
= beta + 1-beta
= 1
```

so it's an affine combination of the values at the corners